# MySQL, Max 3 values

Tags: mysql

I got a table on my website with users rank column, The rank is a number and i wanted to select 3 users with the highest rank number, So i looked and search and the best as far as i think query i found is that: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056162/mysql-select-top-n-max-values)(The second query at the correct answer), But i didn't understand the query, If anyone can can explain step-by-step(For example i didn't understand this line `FROM table li` FROM table is ok **but who is li**, I never saw that kind of syntax), Or suggest better query i will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html#idp67591536

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the three users with the highest rank number, something like this might work:

```
select u.*
from users u
order by rank desc
limit 3;
```

Answer (score 5):

`li` is an alias for the `the table`

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table AS x <-- x is an alias for `my_table`
 WHERE ...
```

The `AS` keyword is optional and frequently omitted

Comment: Hoooooooo, Thank you i didn't know that.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . To further complicate things, if I remember correctly, the `as` is usually optional.  But, it is required in Access and it is forbidden in Oracle.  (I omit it for table aliases, so when I see `as`, I know it is a column alias.)

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is doing multiple subqueries from the same table to use as intermediate results and the names such as "li" are aliases for the same table to ensure the column references belong to the proper subquery. In the example you would use the real table name where it shows "table".