# GROUP BY and get the top two row

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

So I have the following query where it does as i expect it to. It get the latest published article from each aothor. However now I want it to get the latest two article from each author. How can I do this?

```
SELECT author_article.ID
FROM (
       SELECT
         sorted_articles.ID,
         sorted_articles.AuthorID,
         sorted_articles.PublishedDate
       FROM ArticlePage sorted_articles
       ORDER BY PublishedDate DESC
     ) author_article
GROUP BY author_article.AuthorID
ORDER BY author_article.PublishedDate DESC;
```

[image]

So what I need is the latest 2 article for each author.

Comment: Provide some sample data or create a fiddle please

Comment: Search for `greatest-n-per-group`

Comment: @MatBailie It not gratesst there are tons on information on that, What i want is regarding the latest published date.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql select top n max values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056162/mysql-select-top-n-max-values)

Comment: @Colosuslol - It's the same thing, you're looking for the rows with the two greatest `published_date` per group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the authors and the article ids, then this will put them in one row:

```
SELECT ap.AuthorId,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ap.AuthorId ORDER BY ap.PublishedDate DESC
                                   ), ',', 2) as Top2Articles
FROM ArticlePage ap
GROUP BY ap.AuthorId;
```

Note:  the default length for the group concat intermediate value is limited, but can be changed if some authors have lots and lots and lots of articles.

Also, your original query is using a (mis)feature of MySQL that is explicitly documented not to work as you intend.  You have columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  These values come from *indeterminate* rows, so the `ORDER BY` in the subquery may not affect the results the way you intend.

Comment: Well, explicitly documented to not be guaranteed to work.  Subtly different.  Also, creating a comma separated list feels a bit of a SQL-Anti-Pattern; probably worth an outer query to split the values in to two fields or two rows?

Answer (score 3):

Use a correlated sub-query to count all more recent articles by the same author. If there are 1 or less more recent articles, return the row.

```
SELECT *
FROM ArticlePage t1
WHERE (select count(*) from ArticlePage t2
       where t2.AuthorID = t1.AuthorID
         and t2.PublishedDate > t1.PublishedDate) <= 1
```

Comment: While I think a correlated subquery is the right direction, this doesn't quite get what the OP is asking for. If an author has three recent articles it is excluded from your query. It should not exclude them, but rather give the most recent two.

Comment: @davidethell - Your description doesn't account for this line `t2.PublishedDate > t1.PublishedDate`.  If there are three articles, the newest one's correlated sub-query will return `0`, the next newest will return `1` and the next newest will return `2`.  Thus only the third article is excluded by the `<= 1`.

Comment: If a article/author has 1 or less more recent articles, then return it. That's what my query is intended to do. However, it's untested,

Comment: This is working like a charm so far! Ill keep doing some more testing, and mark it as correct! Thank you so mcuh! Still can't understand what is going on tho.

Comment: hmmmm, is it possible for this query to set a Limit for an N amount of authors? For example for 2 authors or 3 authors?

Comment: @Colosuslol - I think that should be a new question, at that point the correlated sub-query approach likely becomes slower than alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Just an other perspective by giving a row_number.

**Query**

```
select t2.articleId,
t2.articleName,
t2.authorName,
t2.publishedDate
from
(
   select articleId,
   articleName,
   authorName,
    publishedDate,
    ( 
        case authorName 
        when @curA
        then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
       else @curRow := 1 and @curA := authorName end
    ) + 1 as rn
    from article t,
    (select @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r
    order by authorName,publishedDate desc
)t2
where t2.rn<3;
```

[Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa791/2)